# ubuntu on android unable to open display chroot

Tags: android, ubuntu, chroot

hello 
I am using ubuntu on android(with chroot)
I am trying to execute xev
(to change the volume button to CTRL)
but every time I trying to open up xev, 
it says 
unable to open the display ''
or
unable to open the display '127.0.0.1:0.0'
(when I change DISPLAY variable with export)

could somebody tell me how to solve this problem?
I can't find official error page on google
your little advice would be very helpful for me
Regards.
Taeyun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0` says to use TCP/IP to connect to the display `0.0`. Distributions haven't configured X servers to listen on TCP for five years or more because it is a needless security risk; you need to remove `-nolisten` from however you execute your `X`, if you really wish to use TCP rather than Unix domain sockets.

But do you really need it to listen on TCP for connections? Seems unlikely -- Unix domain sockets (e.g., `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`) are much more common, just use `DISPLAY=:0.0` to ask for the Unix domain socket instead. You may need to link the socket into your chroot environment, depends on where client and server start from.

Once you can contact the X server from your X client, you also need to authenticate it, using `xauth(1)`. This is annoying :) and is the single most popular reason why everyone just uses SSH X11 forwarding (`ssh -X`) rather than deal with TCP listening and `xauth`  manually. (Incidentally, can you just run an sshd "inside" the chroot on a different port, so you can easily get all this magic for free? :)

Comment: hello~
thank you so much for your replying
unfortunately I am very newbie
so I don't understand what "can you just run an sshd "inside" the chroot on a different port," does it means could you tell me little bit more specified?

Comment: @user464689, can you (1) install sshd inside your chroot (2) edit `/path/to/chroot/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to enable sshd on port `2222`? Then when you `ssh -X localhost:2222` you will connect to the `sshd` running 'inside' the chroot, where hopefully the Unix domain sockets for the X11 inside the chroot "just work".

Comment: thank you ! but.. ssh: could not resolve hostname localhost:2222: Name or service not known surprised I am sorry to sending you a failure message what am I suppose to do?;;

Comment: @user464689, I'm sorry, I _always_ forget that the format is `ssh localhost -p 2222`.

Comment: when I try root@localhost:/#ssh localhost -p 2222 then ssh:could not resolve hostname localhost: name or service not known same as ssh -X localhost -p 2222
not only this command but other command as well

Comment: @user464689, does `ping localhost` work? Try `ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 2222` if `localhost` just never works for you.

Comment: it says ping: unknown host localhost OMG.. what am I suppose to do? and ssh 127.0.0.1 -p 2222 spirit ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2222: connection refused even though I changes sshd_config file any idea?(thank you for your helping anyway)

Comment: @user464689, you could add an entry for `localhost` to `/etc/hosts` :) ... connection refused, that's a tricky spot. Did you re-start sshd while in the chroot?